# Sending data from js to R Shiny variable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm trying to send get request through javascript and bring the response to `input$myinfo`. When I launch the app I can see the file in `Sources` tab of dev tools, but it seems that it's not working.
Here is how my js file looks:

```
$(() => {    
    $.ajax({
        method : "GET",
        url : window.location.origin + "/mypath"        
    })
    .done(data => {
        Shiny.onInputChange('myinfo', JSON.stringify(data.responseJSON));
    })
    .fail(data => {
        console.log(data.responseText);
    });
});
```

It is then loaded in `ui.R` and (as far as I know) runs on app's startup. But it seems that it never goes to `input$myinfo`, as it appears empty. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser JavaScript console? Do you see `Uncaught TypeError: Shiny.onInputChange is not a function`? If so, see https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html. If not, check the WebSocket requests to see if the input change was actually sent.

Comment: @gregL There were no errors in console, though I managed to get it to work with `$(document).ready(function() {` instead of `$(() => {` and some other manipulations I'm not sure I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to utilize the `shiny:connected` event. You are waiting for the document to be ready, but you also need to wait for shiny to be ready. The [JavaScript Events in Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html#initial-connection-session-initialization-and-disconnection) page touches on the related events and provides more details.

I put together a small example. The bare `Shiny.onInputChange(..)` complains that there is no `Shiny` object (see browser developer console) and `input$missing` is `NULL`. However, the `Shiny.onInputChange(..)` that waits on the `shiny:connected` event goes through and `input$found` is `"[1,2,3,4,5]"`.

```
library(shiny)

on_ready <- paste(
  "$(function() {",
  "$(document).on('shiny:connected', function(e) {",
  "Shiny.onInputChange('found', JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));",
  "});",
  "Shiny.onInputChange('missing', JSON.stringify(['where', 'am', 'I?']));",
  "",
  "});",
  sep = "\n"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(on_ready)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      6,
      h5("`input$missing`:"),
      verbatimTextOutput("missingValue"),
      p("(error, Shiny object is missing as connection is not yet established)")
    ),
    column(
      6,
      h5("`input$found`:"),
      verbatimTextOutput("foundValue"),
      p("(no error, wait for `shiny:connected` event)")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$missingValue <- renderPrint({
    input$missing
  })

  output$foundValue <- renderPrint({
    input$found
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The console throws `Uncaught TypeError: Shiny.onInputChange is not a function` , and also How to replicate this in shiny modules. The `foundValue` namespace changes to `someid-foundValue` ?